# Nginx server failing health checks on AWS ELB (Elastic Load Balancer)

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-ec2, reverse-proxy, amazon-elb

I have a node.js server and nginx reverse proxying to it on an EC2 instance hosting a webapp, and I'm trying to set up load balancing via AWS ELB. The server is on a private subnet (testing purposes, nothing is public currently).

The instances is accessible by

1. Connecting to a VPN to access the private subnet and then typing the private ip address in the address bar of my browser. It serves the page just fine.
2. Via ssh
3. I can also ping the instances with `ping ipaddress` and they respond

However ELB claims that all my instances are failing a health check. I initially had the ping target at `/` but I tried different ones and it still claims that the instances are "OutOfService".

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had my security groups configured badly - the instances were blocked from receiving traffic from the load balancer.